# Calculating Height of an Arc at Any Point (math domain error)

Tags: python, mathematics

Please reopen the question.. Reason why?

"This question doesn't seem to be about using Blender or in any way related to the software as defined in the help center"

According What to ask here on the page you refer to I am allowed to ask questions related to Python scripting as related to Blender and add-on development.

My question is in this section. Python scripting for add-on.

Trying to calculate the height offset from X axis using this formula 
(2D not 3D so offset is in Y axis direction and view is from Z to -Z)

[image]

where,

h = unknown (needed) 
s = the sagitta of the arc
 r = the radius of the arc
 x = the horizontal offset from the center to the point where you want the height;

```
r = 1000mm
s = 500mm
x = math.sin(offset)*r (calculate the offset on x axis)

for i in range(8)
   angle = ((math.pi * (i / 8)) * (90 / 180)) # point on circle (1/4 circle // 90 degrees)
   offset = (math.sin(angle)*r)
```

the formula I use

```
h = (s + (sqrt((r**2) - offset**2 - r)))
```

on my calculator no issues at all to calculate this but python keeps giving math domain error.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your python formula doesn't match your latex formula.

Comment: Hi Cecevo, this is a community about Blender user questions. But there are also math specific stack exchange sites...

Comment: Hi @Chris I was not sure if it was just a calculation error or something blender specific.

In the end it was how I wrote the equation as pointed out by Ron Jensen.

It did not solved my issue but it solved the math domain error outcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to add this as a comment, but the code keeps getting mangled.

Your latex formula [image: Your picture] translates to this in Python

```
h = s + sqrt(r**2 - offset**2) - r
```

Your Python is this:

$ h = s + \sqrt{ r^2 - \textrm{offset}^2 - r} $